# Perfomance wise for LUA table selection

Tags: performance, lua

I'm a bit new to LUA. So I have a game that I need to capture the Entity and insert into the table. The maximum possible Entity table that could happen at the same time is 14. So I read that an array based solution is good.

But I saw that the table size increment even if we delete some value, for example from 10 table value and delete value at index 9 its not automatically shift the size when I want to insert table number 11.

Example:

```
 local Table = {"hello", "hello", "hello", "hello", "hello", "hello", "hello", "hello", "hello", "hello"}
 -- Current Table size = 10
 -- Perform delete at index 9
 Table[9] = nil
 -- Have new Entity to insert
 Table[#Table + 1] = "New Value"
 -- The table size will grow by the time the game extend.
```

So for this type of situation did array based table with nil value inside that grow by the time of new table value inserted will have better perfomance or should I move into table with key? 
Or I should just stick with array based table and perform full cleanup when the table isnt used?

Comment: Try `table.remove(Table, 9)`

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff Thanks. Hmm interesting. actually table.remove shift the value. I think I will stick with table.remove instead setting table value to nil. Testing the memory usage have a little improvement since the table size also decrease.

Answer (score 0):

If you set an element in a table to nil, then that just stays there as a "hole" in your array.

```
tab = {1, 2, 3, 4}
tab[2] = nil
-- tab == {1, nil, 3, 4}
-- #tab is actually undefined and could be both 1 or 4 (or something completely unexpected)!
```

What you need to do is set the field to nil, then shift all the following fields to fill that hole. Luckily, Lua has a function for that, which is `table.remove(table, index)`.

```
tab = {1, 2, 3, 4}
table.remove(tab, 2)
-- tab == {1, 3, 4}
-- #tab == 3
```

Keep in mind that this can get very slow as there's lots of memory access involved, so don't go applying this solution when you have a few million elements some day :)

Answer (score 0):

While `table.remove(Table, 9)` will do the job in your case (removing field from "array" table and shifting remaining fields to fill the hole), you should first consider using "set" table instead.

If you:
- often remove/add elements
- don't care about their order
- often check if table contains a certain element

then the "set" table is your choice. Use it like so

```
local tab = {
    ["John"] = true,
    ["Jane"] = true,
    ["Bob"] = true,
}
```

Your elements will be stored as indices in a table.
Remove an element with

```
tab["Jane"] = nil
```

Test if table contains an element with

```
if tab["John"] then
    -- tab contains "John"
```

Advantages compared to array table:
- this will eliminate performance overhead when removing an element because other elements will remain intact and no shifting is required
- checking if element exists in this table (which I assume is the main puspose of this table) is also faster than using array table because it no longer requires iterating over all the elements to find a match, the hash lookup is used instead

Note however that this approach doesn't let you have duplicate values as your elements, because tables can't contain duplicate keys. In that case you can use numbers as values to store the amount of times the element is duplicated in your set, e.g.

```
local tab = {
    ["John"] = 1,
    ["Jane"] = 2,
    ["Bob"] = 35,
}
```

Now you have 1 John, 2 Janes and 35 Bobs

https://www.lua.org/pil/11.5.html

Comment: I believe iterating with `pairs` is a bit slower than `ipairs`. Could anybody confirm this?